# Xbox 360 won't play MPEG-4 video files

Tags: xbox-360

I have MPEG-4 video files on my NAS device that play fine on my PC through Windows Media Player and VLC. However, the Xbox 360 won't play them and displays an error:

```
Can't play this content because it may not be supported.

Status code: 69-C00D002F
```

These video files were created using Corel VideoStudio X4. Other MPEG-4 files created by the converter feature of YouTube Downloader work fine.

MediaInfo displays the following info about the video files:

```
General
Format                           : MPEG-4
Format profile                   : Base Media
Codec ID                         : isom
File size                        : 119 MiB
Duration                         : 3mn 32s
Overall bit rate mode            : Variable
Overall bit rate                 : 4 682 Kbps
Encoded date                     : UTC 2012-04-18 15:14:18
Tagged date                      : UTC 2012-04-18 15:14:18

Video
ID                               : 1
Format                           : AVC
Format/Info                      : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile                   : Main@L3.1
Format settings, CABAC           : Yes
Format settings, ReFrames        : 2 frames
Format settings, GOP             : M=3, N=15
Codec ID                         : avc1
Codec ID/Info                    : Advanced Video Coding
Duration                         : 3mn 32s
Bit rate mode                    : Variable
Bit rate                         : 4 517 Kbps
Maximum bit rate                 : 5 000 Kbps
Width                            : 1 280 pixels
Height                           : 720 pixels
Display aspect ratio             : 16:9
Frame rate mode                  : Constant
Frame rate                       : 30.000 fps
Standard                         : NTSC
Color space                      : YUV
Chroma subsampling               : 4:2:0
Bit depth                        : 8 bits
Scan type                        : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)               : 0.163
Stream size                      : 114 MiB (96%)
Language                         : English
Encoded date                     : UTC 2012-04-18 15:14:18
Tagged date                      : UTC 2012-04-18 15:14:18
Color primaries                  : BT.709-5, BT.1361, IEC 61966-2-4, SMPTE RP177
Transfer characteristics         : BT.709-5, BT.1361
Matrix coefficients              : BT.709-5, BT.1361, IEC 61966-2-4 709, SMPTE RP177

Audio
ID                               : 2
Format                           : AAC
Format/Info                      : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile                   : LC
Codec ID                         : 40
Duration                         : 3mn 32s
Bit rate mode                    : Constant
Bit rate                         : 160 Kbps
Channel(s)                       : 2 channels
Channel positions                : Front: L R
Sampling rate                    : 48.0 KHz
Compression mode                 : Lossy
Stream size                      : 4.06 MiB (3%)
Language                         : English
Encoded date                     : UTC 2012-04-18 15:14:18
Tagged date                      : UTC 2012-04-18 15:14:18
```

I have the "Optional Media Update" installed on the XBox.

Why won't the Xbox play the files?

Comment: Also, based on the information in the MediaInfo, these files should play. Have you tried delivering the content to the 360 via an alternate means (Physical media or memory stick or something) to determine if it's a problem with the delivery system or the playback itself?

Comment: Nope haven't tried physical media because other videos do play fine, so I think delivery is working properly. Videos also play fine on the Windows PC and iPhone 4 when streamed from the NAS over DLNA.

Comment: Thanks for posting the error. That was very helpful. In the video files that play correctly, does the MediaInfo list the audio bit rate mode as Variable or Constant? If Variable, then it may relate to [this error](https://getsatisfaction.com/microsoft/topics/error_code_69_c00d002f_when_playing_some_mp4_on_the_xbox_360) and indicate that it was never resolved.

Comment: Did you try encoding with Variable bit rate audio from Corel VideoStudio X4 to see if that did the trick?

Comment: There isn't an option for variable bit rate for audio. It just lets me pick a constant value e.g. 160, 128, etc.

Comment: Interestingly, when I run the **YouTube Downloader** tool and convert the file from MP4 to MP4, it changes the audio from constant to variable. The converted file will play on the XBox.

Comment: I am trying to find out whether converting just the audio from CBR to VBR will get the file working. I've asked a question [here](http://avp.stackexchange.com/questions/3789/how-can-i-convert-the-aac-audio-in-an-mp4-from-cbr-to-vbr) on how to actually do this.

Comment: I've converted the video file so that the audio is now VBR but the video track is the same as before. While it plays on Windows and iPhone, it still doesn't play on the XBox.

Comment: Without seeing the MediaInfo that did play, it's a little hard to narrow down the individual setting or group of settings that are a problem here. Obviously Youtube Downloader's settings work. If Corel doesn't let you change the settings all that specifically, the interim solution may well be to pass the videos through Youtube Downloader.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3182/discussion-between-skovacs1-and-giddyuphorsey)

Comment: I found that running ffmpeg -i <input file>.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec aac -ab 192k -ac 2 -threads 0 -strict experimental <output file>.mp4 got rid of the error. I think this converts the audio to stereo.

Answer (score 4):

Media files compatibility are not determined only by the container (ie, mp4) but also by the codecs used. Just because the codecs you use in the YouTube tool work with the Xbox, does not necessarily mean that those used by the Corel product will.

The supported formats for the Xbox 360 are listed on [Microsoft's support page](http://support.xbox.com/en-GB/xbox-360/settings-and-initial-setup/watch-dvds-movies)

You will notice that the "Advanced Video Coding" you have used is missing there, as that is in fact for MPEG-4/H264, rather than the MPEG-4 Part 2 that Microsoft have chosen to support.

I would suggest looking in the settings for your Corel Studio program and seeing if there's a choice for format/codec.

Comment: Actually, even if not listed clearly, Xbox 360 does support AVC encoded MP4s with stereo audio [even as of 2008](http://www.afterdawn.com/guides/archive/what_will_xbox_360_play.cfm). "The Xbox 360 seems very picky about multi-channel AAC audio in an MP4 container with an AVC video stream, while it plays stereo AAC perfectly fine" and "we had 720p and 1080p tests for AVC video in the MP4 container, and again, received no error (unless audio other than AAC was present)". Any simple search will yield further user confirmation of AVC encoded MP4 functionality on 360.

Answer (score 1):

It's the sample rate... Xbox 360 no likey 48.0khz.  I've confirmed this by converting movies using 48. khz down to 44.1khz and was able to stream it.  NOt sure what the point of using 48khz since almost all audio other than hi def uses 44.1 and is normally the standard.

Comment: No, it's not the 48.0KHz.  I have a MP4 right here that plays through the 360: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 148 kb/s